# After importing a database data, enabling binary logging just wiped it

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform

Me and my colleagues are testing GCP functionalities and this morning finished importing a mySQL database successfully.

[image: SQL Database storage]

After that, my colleague went into the settings and enabled Binary Loggings.
Save confirmed the `save and restart` action.

As you can see from the image, the DB went from 35GB to 1GB. All data was wiped clean. Only the table structures remains.

This is an extract of the logs for the event: https://pastebin.com/4kNj08CY

Can someone clarify why this happens?